# build spark docker image

Tags: docker, apache-spark, kubernetes

according to documentation:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html i try to build spark docker image by the following command:

```
./docker-image-tool.sh  -t 3.1.1 build
```

however, I got this error:

```
Could not wait for server fd - select (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) [IP: xxxxx 8080]
   Err:6 https://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates Release
     Could not handshake: Error in the pull function. [IP: xxxxx 8080]
   Reading package lists...
   E: The repository 'https://deb.debian.org/debian buster Release' does not have a Release file.
   E: The repository 'https://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
   The command '/bin/sh -c set -ex &&     sed -i 's/http:\/\/deb.\(.*\)/https:\/\/deb.\1/g' /etc/apt/sources.list &&     apt-get update &&     ln -s /lib /lib64 &&     apt install -y bash tini libc6 libpam-modules krb5-user libnss3 procps &&     mkdir -p /opt/spark &&     mkdir -p /opt/spark/examples &&     mkdir -p /opt/spark/work-dir &&     touch /opt/spark/RELEASE &&     rm /bin/sh &&     ln -sv /bin/bash /bin/sh &&     echo "auth required pam_wheel.so use_uid" >> /etc/pam.d/su &&     chgrp root /etc/passwd && chmod ug+rw /etc/passwd &&     rm -rf /var/cache/apt/*' returned a non-zero code: 100
   Failed to build Spark JVM Docker image, please refer to Docker build output for details
```

Any help please?

Comment: It seems like a network issue. Do you have any proxy configured on your server ?
Can you run the `apt-get update` command without any error on your server ?

Comment: @matt_j, i need to add sudo before in order to run **apt-get update**

Comment: True, I think any `apt-get install/update/upgrade` command is enough to test if it works as expected on your k8s node.

Comment: @matt_j: and what you suggest as solution?